# getStaticPaths for dynamic route catching all routes [[...Id]].js in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I developed small application with catch all route method url is http://localhost:3000/category/fashion/19see the bellow image
[image]

Now I am using getServerSideProps method working fine, and changed to getStaticProps method error displayed, bu want use getStaticPaths method, I got dynamic values using context.params.Id[0]=fashion and context.params.Id1=19, But can not call this value inside of getStaticPaths, What I am missing and can you please solve this issue please.

category/[...Id].js

```
 import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import { Grid, Image,Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react" 
    import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
    import Layout from '../../components/layout'
    
    
    const Post = (props) => {
      const router = useRouter()
      const { Id } = router.query
      console.log(props.category_list)  
      return(
        <>
        <Layout>
        <Head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
                {/* <meta name="description" content={seo_description} /> */}
                <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
                <meta name="google-site-verification" content="rtIRrUNRpgZ_lFtlfS8LJ0-8j_d569BXS9NOGa_nM6Y" />
                
              </Head>  
          <Grid className="store-list">
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
              <p>
                <span>{props.category_title.heading_label}</span>
              </p>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid>
          <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers storeList">
            {props.category_list.map((x) => {
              return (
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Segment>
                    <Card>
                      <a href  ={x.store_url}>
                        {" "}
                        <Image
                          src={x.image}
                          alt=""
                          className="collection-img"
                        ></Image>
                      </a>
                      <Card.Content>
                        <a href  ={x.store_url}>
                          {" "}
                          <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                        </a>
                        <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                      </Card.Content>
                      <Card.Content extra>
                        <p className="rewards">
                          <span>
                            <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                          </span>
                          Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                        </p>
                        <p className="location">
                          <span>
                            <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                          </span>
                          <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                          {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                            <span className="store-location">
                              {index === 0 ? (
                                <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                              ) : index >= 1 ? (
                                <span>
                                  ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                                </span>
                              ) : null}
                            </span>
                          ))} */}
                        </p>
                      </Card.Content>
                    </Card>
                  </Segment>
                </Grid.Column>
              );
            })}
          </Grid> 
          </Layout>
        </>
    
      )
    }
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
 // How to call context value here
  return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
  }
    export async function getStaticProps(context) {
      const id = context.params.Id[1];
      const postBody = {
        category_id: id,
        offer_type: "",
      };
      const offerList = await fetch('https://lenapp.ae/api/v5/web/list',{
        method:'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      })
      const category = await offerList.json();
        // const bookJson = JSON.stringify(book)
        // const bookJson=offerData.stores;
      const category_list=category.stores;
      const category_title=category;
      return {
        props: {
          category_list,
          category_title
        }
      };
    }
     
    export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    //How to call context value here - explaining
    const res = await fetch('your_api_path')
    const posts = await res.json()
    //params: {id: post.id} - this is your value will be fashion or 19, check the data/field you receiving
    const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
          params: { id: post.id },
    }))
    return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

For the nested dynamic routes: You can create `/category/[style](folder)/[id](file)`. I suggest you make firstly with `getServerSideProps` all your pages and routing, and then do with `getStaticProps`.

Comment: I followed you suggestion not working can you please update my code.

Comment: I got error Error: A required parameter (Id) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /category/[...Id]

Comment: You're using the spread routing, so the id needs to be an array of all the potential URLs, so once you've fetched all the pages, you'll need to structure the params like this `id: [ "fashion", "19" ]`